# Frama-C: Get slice for C assert statement

Tags: frama-c, program-slicing

Is there a way to use `Frama-C`'s slicing plugin to compute slices for a specific C `assert` statement?

For example, given the following code:

```
int main() {
    double a=3;
    double b=4;
    double c=123;

    assert(b>=0);

    double d=a/b;
    c=a;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to get the following slice for `assert(b>=0);`:

```
int main() {
    double b=4;

    assert(b>=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can rewrite your assert as an ACSL assertion, you can use option `-slice-assert main`.

```
int main() {
    double a=3;
    double b=4;
    double c=123;

    //@ assert(b>=0);

    double d=a/b;
    c=a;

    return 0;
}
```

(In this case, the division will also be removed, as it does not influence the assertion.)

```
void main(void)
{
  double b;
  b = (double)4;
  /*@ assert b ≥ 0; */ ;
  return;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also slice on the calls to the `assert` function, using `-slice-calls assert`.

```
void main(void)
{
  double b;
  b = (double)4;
  assert(b >= (double)0);
  return;
}
```

If you want to slice on a particular assertion (if there are more than one in the function), you will have to use a slicing pragma, or the programmatic API (not recommended).

Comment: I need to slice for a particular statement in the code (thus I assume that there are multiple ones). So I thought about developing a Frama-C plugin which does the job. Would you recommend doing that? Or is that what you meant by "`programmatic API (not recommended)`"? Alternatively I could preprocess the Frama-C-preprocessed code using regular expressions.

Comment: Also I guess that if there is more than one assert statements in the code and I want to slice on a particular one, it would suffice to convert that statement into an ACSL assertion, wouldn't it?

Comment: For this kind of thing, perhaps you should use a slicing pragma as described in http://frama-c.com/slicing.html. Basically, just write `/*@ slice pragma stmt; */`, and use option `-slice-pragma`.